# Phonegap/Cordova not showing camera

Tags: ios5, cordova, camera

I have a weird problem with my first phonegap/cordova app for ios

i copy pasted the examples from 
http://docs.phonegap.com/en/2.3.0/cordova_camera_camera.md.html#camera.getPicture

and

http://docs.phonegap.com/en/2.3.0/cordova_media_capture_capture.md.html#capture.captureImage

But when i press any of the buttons nothing happens, unless i double-tap the "home"-button on the iphone afterwards.

Here is my index.html:

```
    <script src="assets/js/cordova.ios.js"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">
    var pictureSource;   // picture source
    var destinationType; // sets the format of returned value 

    // Wait for Cordova to connect with the device
    document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);

    // Cordova is ready to be used!
    function onDeviceReady() {
        pictureSource = navigator.camera.PictureSourceType;
        destinationType = navigator.camera.DestinationType;
    }

    // Called when a photo is successfully retrieved
    function onPhotoDataSuccess(imageData) {
        // Uncomment to view the base64 encoded image data
        // console.log(imageData);

        // Get image handle
        var smallImage = document.getElementById('smallImage');

        // Unhide image elements
        smallImage.style.display = 'block';

        // Show the captured photo
        // The inline CSS rules are used to resize the image
        smallImage.src = "data:image/jpeg;base64," + imageData;
    }

    // Called when a photo is successfully retrieved
    function onPhotoURISuccess(imageURI) {
        // Uncomment to view the image file URI 
        // console.log(imageURI);

        // Get image handle
        var largeImage = document.getElementById('largeImage');

        // Unhide image elements
        largeImage.style.display = 'block';

        // Show the captured photo
        // The inline CSS rules are used to resize the image
        largeImage.src = imageURI;
    }

    // A button will call this function
    function capturePhoto() {
        // Take picture using device camera and retrieve image as base64-encoded string
        navigator.camera.getPicture(onPhotoDataSuccess, onFail, {
            quality: 50,
            destinationType: destinationType.DATA_URL
        });
    }

    // A button will call this function
    function capturePhotoEdit() {
        // Take picture using device camera, allow edit, and retrieve image as base64-encoded string  
        navigator.camera.getPicture(onPhotoDataSuccess, onFail, {
            quality: 20, allowEdit: true,
            destinationType: destinationType.DATA_URL
        });
    }

    // A button will call this function
    function getPhoto(source) {
        // Retrieve image file location from specified source
        navigator.camera.getPicture(onPhotoURISuccess, onFail, {
            quality: 50,
            destinationType: destinationType.FILE_URI,
            sourceType: source
        });
    }

    // Called if something bad happens.
    function onFail(message) {
        alert('Failed because: ' + message);
    }
    </script>
    <button onclick="capturePhoto();">Capture Photo</button>  
    <button onclick="capturePhotoEdit();">Capture Editable Photo</button>  
    <button onclick="getPhoto(pictureSource.PHOTOLIBRARY);">From Photo Library</button>  
    <button onclick="getPhoto(pictureSource.SAVEDPHOTOALBUM);">From Photo Album</button>  
    <img style="display:none;width:60px;height:60px;" id="smallImage" src="" />  
    <img style="display:none;" id="largeImage" src="" />  


    <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">

    // Called when capture operation is finished
    function captureSuccess(mediaFiles) {
        //var i, len;
        //for (i = 0, len = mediaFiles.length; i < len; i += 1) {
        //    //uploadFile(mediaFiles[i]);
        //}
        //navigator.notification.alert('Weee', null, 'Great success!');
    }

    // Called if something bad happens.
    function captureError(error) {
        //var msg = 'An error occurred during capture: ' + error.code;
        //navigator.notification.alert(msg, null, 'Uh oh!');
    }

    // A button will call this function
        function captureImage() {
        // Launch device camera application, 
        // allowing user to capture up to 2 images
        navigator.device.capture.captureImage(captureSuccess, captureError, { limit: 2     });
    }

    // Upload files to server
    function uploadFile(mediaFile) {
        var ft = new FileTransfer(),
            path = mediaFile.fullPath,
            name = mediaFile.name;

        ft.upload(path,
            "http://my.domain.com/upload.php",
            function (result) {
                console.log('Upload success: ' + result.responseCode);
                console.log(result.bytesSent + ' bytes sent');
            },
            function (error) {
                console.log('Error uploading file ' + path + ': ' + error.code);
            },
            { fileName: name });
    }
    </script>

    <button onclick="captureImage();">Capture Image</button>
```

and here is my config.xml:

```
    <name>yadda</name>

    <description>
        blabla
    </description>

    <author href="http://blabla.github.com"
    email="blabla@gmail.com">
        BlaBla
    </author>

    <icon src="icon.png" gap:role="default" />

    <feature name="http://api.phonegap.com/1.0/geolocation"/>
    <feature name="http://api.phonegap.com/1.0/network"/>
    <feature name="http://api.phonegap.com/1.0/file"/>
    <feature name="http://api.phonegap.com/1.0/camera"/>
    <feature name="http://api.phonegap.com/1.0/media"/>
    <feature name="http://api.phonegap.com/1.0/device"/>

    <preference name="orientation" value="portrait" />
    <preference name="webviewbounce" value="false" />
    <preference name="prerendered-icon" value="true" />

    <plugin name="Capture" value="CDVCapture" />
    <plugin name="Camera" value="CDVCamera" />
```

does anyone have an idea as to what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

YES! i finally got it to work, i downgraded from phonegap 2.3.0 to 2.0.0

For anyone with the same problem here is my final code:

index.html

```
    <script src="assets/js/cordova-2.0.0.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">

        // Called when capture operation is finished
        //
        function captureSuccess(mediaFiles) {
            //var i, len;
            //for (i = 0, len = mediaFiles.length; i < len; i += 1) {
            //    //uploadFile(mediaFiles[i]);
            //}
            //navigator.notification.alert('Weee', null, 'Great success!');
        }

        // Called if something bad happens.
        // 
        function captureError(error) {
            //var msg = 'An error occurred during capture: ' + error.code;
            //navigator.notification.alert(msg, null, 'Uh oh!');
        }

        // A button will call this function
        //
        function captureImage() {
            // Launch device camera application, 
            // allowing user to capture up to 2 images
            navigator.device.capture.captureImage(captureSuccess, captureError, { limit: 2 });
        }

        // Upload files to server
        function uploadFile(mediaFile) {
            var ft = new FileTransfer(),
                path = mediaFile.fullPath,
                name = mediaFile.name;

            ft.upload(path,
                "http://my.domain.com/upload.php",
                function (result) {
                    console.log('Upload success: ' + result.responseCode);
                    console.log(result.bytesSent + ' bytes sent');
                },
                function (error) {
                    console.log('Error uploading file ' + path + ': ' + error.code);
                },
                { fileName: name });
        }
    </script>


    <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">

        var pictureSource;   // picture source
        var destinationType; // sets the format of returned value 

        // Wait for Cordova to connect with the device
        //
        function onLoad() { document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false); }

        // Cordova is ready to be used!
        //
        function onDeviceReady() {
            pictureSource = navigator.camera.PictureSourceType;
            destinationType = navigator.camera.DestinationType;
            alert("device is ready");
        }

        // Called when a photo is successfully retrieved
        //
        function onPhotoDataSuccess(imageData) {
            // Uncomment to view the base64 encoded image data
            // console.log(imageData);

            // Get image handle
            //
            var smallImage = document.getElementById('smallImage');

            // Unhide image elements
            //
            smallImage.style.display = 'block';

            // Show the captured photo
            // The inline CSS rules are used to resize the image
            //
            smallImage.src = "data:image/jpeg;base64," + imageData;
        }

        // Called when a photo is successfully retrieved
        //
        function onPhotoURISuccess(imageURI) {
            // Uncomment to view the image file URI 
            // console.log(imageURI);

            // Get image handle
            //
            var largeImage = document.getElementById('largeImage');

            // Unhide image elements
            //
            largeImage.style.display = 'block';

            // Show the captured photo
            // The inline CSS rules are used to resize the image
            //
            largeImage.src = imageURI;
        }

        // A button will call this function
        //
        function capturePhoto() {
            // Take picture using device camera and retrieve image as base64-encoded string
            navigator.camera.getPicture(onPhotoDataSuccess, onFail, {
                quality: 50,
                destinationType: destinationType.DATA_URL
            });
        }

        // A button will call this function
        //
        function capturePhotoEdit() {
            // Take picture using device camera, allow edit, and retrieve image as base64-encoded string  
            navigator.camera.getPicture(onPhotoDataSuccess, onFail, {
                quality: 20, allowEdit: true,
                destinationType: destinationType.DATA_URL
            });
        }

        // A button will call this function
        //
        function getPhoto(source) {
            // Retrieve image file location from specified source
            navigator.camera.getPicture(onPhotoURISuccess, onFail, {
                quality: 50,
                destinationType: destinationType.FILE_URI,
                sourceType: source
            });
        }

        // Called if something bad happens.
        // 
        function onFail(message) {
            alert('Failed because: ' + message);
        }

    </script>
</head>
<body onLoad="onLoad()">
    <button onclick="capturePhoto();">Capture Photo</button> <br><br>
    <button onclick="capturePhotoEdit();">Capture Editable Photo</button> <br><br>
    <button onclick="getPhoto(pictureSource.PHOTOLIBRARY);">From Photo Library</button><br><br>
    <button onclick="getPhoto(pictureSource.SAVEDPHOTOALBUM);">From Photo Album</button><br><br>
    <img style="display:none;width:60px;height:60px;" id="smallImage" src="" />
    <img style="display:none;" id="largeImage" src="" />
    <br><button onclick="captureImage();">Capture Image</button> <br>
```

config.xml

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<widget xmlns       = "http://www.w3.org/ns/widgets"
xmlns:gap   = "http://phonegap.com/ns/1.0"
id      = "com.phonegap.getting.started"
version     = "1.0.0">

<name>bla</name>

<description>
    bla
</description>

<author href="http://bla.github.com"
    email="bla@gmail.com">
    bla
</author>

<icon src="icon.png" gap:role="default" />

<feature name="http://api.phonegap.com/1.0/geolocation"/>
<feature name="http://api.phonegap.com/1.0/network"/>
  <feature name="http://api.phonegap.com/1.0/file"/>
  <feature name="http://api.phonegap.com/1.0/camera"/>
  <feature name="http://api.phonegap.com/1.0/media"/>
  <feature name="http://api.phonegap.com/1.0/device"/>

  <feature name="http://api.phonegap.com/1.0/notification"/>
  <feature name="http://api.phonegap.com/1.0/battery"/>

<preference name="orientation" value="portrait" />
<preference name="webviewbounce" value="false" />
<preference name="prerendered-icon" value="true" />
  <preference name="phonegap-version" value="2.0.0" />

  <preference name="fullscreen" value="false" />
  <preference name="stay-in-webview" value="false" />
  <preference name="ios-statusbarstyle" value="default" />
  <preference name="android-minSdkVersion" value="7" />
  <preference name="android-installLocation" value="internalOnly" />
  <preference name="target-device" value="universal" />
  <preference name="autohide-splashscreen" value="true" />
  <preference name="load-url-timeout" value="60000" />
  <preference name="show-splashscreen-spinner" value="true" />
  <preference name="show-splash-screen-spinner" value="true" />
  <preference name="allow-inline-media-playback" value="false" />
  <preference name="launch-mode" value="standard" />


  <plugin name="Capture" value="CDVCapture" />
  <plugin name="Camera" value="CDVCamera" />
</widget>
```

THANKS! to everyone who helped :)

Comment: How do you test work this? Do you do it on your phone in web or you need to build it in Phonegap Build first

Answer (score 1):

I dont have any experience with ios but i think better you do a simple code to open camera something like

```
    navigator.camera.getPicture(onSuccess, onFail, { quality: 50, 
        destinationType: Camera.DestinationType.FILE_URI }); 

    function onSuccess(imageURI) {
        var image = document.getElementById('myImage');
        image.src = imageURI;
    }

    function onFail(message) {
        alert('Failed because: ' + message);
    }
```

If this works fine add your further code step by step.

These are preferences in using in xml

```
    <preference name="orientation" value="landscape" />
    <preference name="fullscreen" value="false" />
    <preference name="phonegap-version" value="2.0.0" />
    <preference name="webviewbounce" value="false" />
    <preference name="stay-in-webview" value="false" />
    <preference name="ios-statusbarstyle" value="default" />
    <preference name="android-minSdkVersion" value="7" />
    <preference name="android-installLocation" value="internalOnly" />
    <preference name="prerendered-icon" value="false" />
    <preference name="target-device" value="universal" />
    <preference name="autohide-splashscreen" value="false" />
    <preference name="load-url-timeout" value="60000" />
    <preference name="show-splashscreen-spinner" value="true" />
    <preference name="show-splash-screen-spinner" value="true" />
    <preference name="allow-inline-media-playback" value="false" />
    <preference name="launch-mode" value="standard" />

    <plugin name="Camera" value="CDVCamera" />
    <feature name="http://api.phonegap.com/1.0/camera"/>
    <feature name="http://api.phonegap.com/1.0/file"/>
    <feature name="http://api.phonegap.com/1.0/media"/>
    <feature name="http://api.phonegap.com/1.0/notification"/>
    <feature name="http://api.phonegap.com/1.0/battery"/>
    <feature name="http://api.phonegap.com/1.0/device"/>
```

Comment: ill try to use your code instead. brb

on a sidenote: i tried replacing the cordova.js for ios with the one for android. And my code worked flawlessly...

Comment: nope. the result is exactly the same. After pressing "Capture image", I have to doubletap the homebutton before it switches to the camera :(

Comment: can you check the deviceready event is working perfect? also which version of ios do you have? cordova 2.3.0  dropped  iOS 4.x support and only supporting iOS 5.0 and greater, going forward.

Comment: (Reference) http://shazronatadobe.wordpress.com/2012/12/10/whats-new-in-cordova-ios-2-3-0/

Comment: ok there is a alternative option for taking image try using navigator.device.capture.captureImage( 
    CaptureCB captureSuccess, CaptureErrorCB captureError, [CaptureImageOptions options]
);
ref: http://docs.phonegap.com/en/2.3.0/cordova_media_capture_capture.md.html#capture.captureImage

Just put this inside the deviceready event. Also read the ios Quirks mentioned in doc

Comment: still the same. Its as if the camera-app starts in the background and you have to switch to it manually...

Could it be some weird permission settings i have overlooked?

Comment: <plugin name="Camera" value="CDVCamera" /> This is the permission for ios i can see you added it in the xml file. just change the version of phone gap to 2.0.0 and try again may be problem of phonegap. are you using phonegap build?

Comment: Also see my edit in the post These are preferences im using try to add inside your xml.

Answer (score 1):

This may be due to mismatch between downloaded version of PhoneGap and sample code of Camera.
You can check camera sample code version on top-right bar of Phonegap.com as show in below screenshot.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Try adding a body tag to your document and something like:

```
<body onLoad="onLoad()">
```

Then add the device ready listener to the onLoad function:

```
function onLoad() { document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false); }
```

This is because you want to make sure all of the DOM elements are loaded before you check the deviceready state.

Comment: His deviceready state is firing you could read the comments before.

Comment: It is, but is it firing before the full DOM is load? Because if it is, the following functions may be trying to interact with elements that aren't loaded yet. That was my point